# RobotFramework: Test that a download link works

Tags: robotframework

I have a web page that i need to click a download link of. Ive got this far and i can see manually that the file is downloaded. How do i (in Robot) verify that the file is downloaded correctly on this?

Comment: You could download the file and then use `run process` within the process library to check the contents of the download folder? On the top of my head this is what I would do...

Comment: What is the validation of "correctness" of the file? The filename, bytes size, Checksum? Depends of how you want to check. Another option is the OperatingSystem Library (http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html).

Comment: I believe using of Requests library could be helpful and test the response. Of course it will be more like API test than UI test, but on the other hand, I guess it might be the best option for checking files...